# How to join a pk with an range

Tags: sql, join, range

I have the following tables:

TABLE A

```
PK VALUE
----------
01 AA
03 BB
07 CC
19 DD
```

TABLE B

```
FROM TO VALUE
------------------
01   04 ZZ
05   10 YY
11   20 XX
```

I would like to join those two tables so that `PK` from table A matches the range `from`-`to` from table B.

The desired result would be:

```
PK VALUE FROM TO VALUE
----------------------
01 AA    01   04 ZZ
03 BB    01   04 ZZ
07 CC    05   10 YY
19 DD    11   20 XX
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Which dbms you are using (mysql, tsql / sql-server, oracle, postgresql, mariadb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT A.PK, A.VALUE, B.[FROM], B.[TO], B.VALUE
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.PK BETWEEN B.[FROM] AND B.[TO]
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb55d6bdef97796c4bce1155fab76536)

---

You consider to remove the ranges and using exact values instead. [A comparison of these two solutions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7a7666163cca21d767aad042ab5d7e0) on MSSMS shows the following:

[image]

So your current solution is not that inefficient.

Comment: Isn't this too resource consuming? we are considering changeing the from-to with a exact value and add all the needed lines to  the table. Which one would be more efficient? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` with a `between` condition:

```
select ta.*, tb.*
from tablea ta
inner join tableb tb on ta.pk between tb.from and tb.to
```

Or use do explicit comparisons:

```
select ta.*, tb.*
from tablea ta
inner join tableb tb 
    on  ta.pk >= tb.from 
    and ta.pk <= tb.to
```